# What is the Silverlight keycode for a dash "-"

Tags: silverlight

I've tried `Key.Subtract` but I think that is the numpad version. I'm looking for the one after the zero key.

I wish to handle it in a `KeyDown` event.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for an endash, an emdash, or a minus sign?

Comment: I'm not sure what to call it. On my keyboard its shift char is an underscore. It comes after the zero and before the "plus/equals" key. Ideally I'm looking for the Window.Input.Key enumerated value for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick debug shows the that it comes through as `Key.Unknown` as do other keys such as `[` and `]`

So it looks like you can't (easily) distinguish when this key is pressed.

The MSDN page for [`System.Windows.Input.Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(VS.95).aspx) enumeration lists all the values, which is significantly shorter than [the .NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key.aspx) version.

However, if you look at `e.PlatformKeyCode` this might give you the value you need. However, the [help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.platformkeycode(VS.95).aspx) for this states:

> This value is the nonportable key code, which is operating system–specific.

The remarks are more extensive:

> The portable key codes are a common subset of all the possible key codes of the supported operating systems, in this case, Macintosh and Windows. For example, the keystroke 'v' is represented as a Key value (which would evaluate as 51 if you cast it to an integer, but is more useful if you retain the enumeration information). That key would have a **PlatformKeyCode** value of 86. Certain keystrokes, however, are not portable, such as the SCROLL LOCK key for Microsoft Windows. In this case, the **Key** value is [Unknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(VS.95).aspx), which is the value for any nonportable key, and the **PlatformKeyCode** is 145 on a Windows platform. For information about Microsoft Windows-specific key codes, see "Virtual-Key Codes" in the [MSDN Library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=37118). For information on Macintosh-specific key codes, see `Keyboard Layout Services Reference` (broken link removed) on the Apple Developer Connection Web site.

On my setup (Chrome in Windows XP) "-" is 189

Comment: Ughh. Man, that's not good. Is there a lower level way of determining when that key is hit so I can tell it apart from [ ] keys ?